# Can't import @restController in my spring restful web services project

Tags: xml, spring, rest, maven, web-services

[@restController can't be imported](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19sgyrV4o4CZMtjIpOmHPUUp6D9_6NZvE)

I am making a spring restful web service using maven so i put my `pom.xml` file to see why I couldn't import `@restController` annotation 
That annotation depend on the dependencies of the pom file.

Comment: SO users don't code with you and don't know what you're talking about.... If you don't explain we cannot understand the problem .... Start by making an effort by putting your code rather than links for example ....

Comment: I am making a spring restful web service using maven so i put my pom.xml file to see why i couldn't import @restController annotation >>>that annotation depend on the dependencies of the pom file

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. In short dumping a link to a `pom.xml` isn't going to help you get an answer.

Comment: U have to add suitable versions of jars in your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks guys, it solved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

With very little to go on try adding the above xml to your pom above the dependencies (the version may not be correct so please double check that too).